# Understanding IO.puts with elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to simply print the result of a comprehension to the console using Elixir. Here is the problem and the code I'm trying to print:

```
range = 1..999

multiple_of_3? = fn(n) -> rem(n, 3) == 0 end
multiple_of_5? = fn(n) -> rem(n, 5) == 0 end
import Integer
IO.puts for n <- range, multiple_of_3?.(n), multiple_of_5?.(n), do: n
```

Pretty straightforward. The only problem is when I run this from the console this is what I get back:

```
<KZix¥´ÃÒáðÿĎĝĬĻŊřŨŷƆƕƤƳǂǑǠǯǾȍȜȫȺɉɘɧɶʅʔʣʲˁː˟ˮ˽̛̪̹͈̌͗ͦ͵΄Γ΢απϏϞ
```

That is not what I'm looking for needless to say. Why is this not printing the actual numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out a map's array values in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804904/how-to-print-out-a-maps-array-values-in-elixir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean `IO.inspect` instead of `IO.puts`? [`IO.puts`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#puts/2) will interpret the list as character data.

```rb
iex(15)> IO.puts [15,30,45]  
^O^^-
:ok
iex(14)> IO.puts <<15,30,45>>
^O^^-
:ok
```

Comment: `IO.puts` won’t _interpret_ anything, it receives a charlist as an argument and it spits it out.

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you for your comment. That would depend on how you interpret the word, "interpret." :)